# Using gdal's python library to generate Esri JSON

Tags: gdal, geometry

I have the need/requirement to use Esri JSON to query some services. I noticed that there is a `CreateGeometryFromEsriJson` but I can't seem to figure out how to take the new geometry object and convert it back into EsriJSON.  Is there a method to do this in gdal?

I know there are methods using `arcpy` but I cannot use `arcpy` for this situation and am limited to gdal.  I do not wish to use any other 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Is there anything special about ESRI JSON (other than it's proprietary nature) that prevents you using GeoJSON?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to generate ESRI JSON with GDAL because the ESRIJSON driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/esrijson.html can only read, but not write ESRI JSON.

> This driver can read the JSON output of Feature Service requests
> following the GeoServices REST Specification, like implemented by
> ArcGIS Server REST API.